# Running Multiple ONNX Model for Inferencing in Parallel in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, onnxruntime

Is there a way to run multiple ONNX models in parallel and use multiple cores available?

Currently, I have trained two ONNX models and want to infer using them. I have used threading from Python but that doesn’t really use multiple cores.

After that I tried multiprocessing but that gives me below error:

> can't pickle onnxruntime.capi.onnxruntime_pybind11_state.SessionOptions objects

Please let me know if there is any workaround to this?

Comment: You need to post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) if anyone (not necessarily I) is going to give you a helpful response.

Answer (score 2):

STEP 1:
If you running you are running application on GPU following solution will be helpful.

```
import multiprocessing
```

CUDA runtime does not support the fork start method so use spawn, like below before you multi process call:

```
multiprocessing.set_start_method('spawn')
```

More understanding please ref: https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime/issues/7846

STEP2:
You need to pass your refereed object in individual process memory or you can use shared memory approach also like below:

```
 from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager
 from PythonFile import ClassName

 BaseManager.register('LabelName', ClassName)
 manager = BaseManager()
 manager.start()
 obj = manager.ClassName()
```

Now you can pass this "obj" to process call as an argument that can be then accessible in all your multiple processes.